# Installing ORA2PG tool on windows 12R2 server

Tags: ora2pg

This is 1st time here. I am trying to install ora2pg tool to migrate data from oracle 12c to PG20. As per docs, I installed Strawberry Perl and ActiveState Perl on the Windows server where I have Oracle 12c enterprise version (and not the client) installed. On the same machine, I have postgresql installed. When I type gmake.exe on c:\ora2pg20\ I get this error message:

> :to undefined at c:\perl64\site\lib\extutils\install.pm line 141.

Is it because I could not get to install DBD::Oracle? Or I am missing something else? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I had to get ora2pg running earlier today on my Win10 and faced the same issues.

I had also installed Strawberry Perl and ActiveState Perl - and found that the PATH envvar ended up being confused with having multiple Perl environments.

So I got rid of ActiveState PERL and made sure my PATH envvar was correct for Strawberry Perl.

Then I got DBD::Oracle from
https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MJ/MJEVANS/DBD-Oracle-1.80.tar.gz

After installing ora2pg and DBD::Oracle via the standard Perl Makefile process, and creating a valid ora2pg.conf file for my particular Oracle instance, it all started to work.

Good luck